# How to auto update a price based on form field type="number"

Tags: javascript, input, field, auto-update

If I have created an order form, and want to allow the user to select the product quantity using a number-based input using form type of "number", what event would you use to fire a calculation of total cost? I've tried oninput, but it simply outputs the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'oninput'"

For example, this code:

`<label>Number of products:</label>
<input name="product" id="product" type="number" />
Total Value: $ <span id="result"></span>​`

and calculation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#product').oninput(function(){
    jQuery('#result').text(jQuery('#product').val() * 25.99);
});
```

});​

http://jsfiddle.net/7BDwP/806/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#product').change(function(){
        $('#result').text($(this).val() * 25.99);
    });    
});​
```

Also, you might want to add a minimum value for your input field:

```
<input name="shares" id="product" type="number" min=0 />
```

Comment: `change` seems to work for clicking the increment/decrement buttons, but not on keyup.

Comment: Working with keys: http://jsfiddle.net/radu/6QsFq/ in Chrome 20. What browser are you using?

Comment: Interesting, Chrome 20 as well. I found I had to make [the following edits](http://jsfiddle.net/7BDwP/810/) to get it working, relying on jQuery >= 1.7

Comment: Ah ok, it's only updating the value after keypress when losing focus, whereas binding to both 'change' and 'keyup' updates immediately.

Comment: Odd.. I'm seeing it updating immediately in either case.

Comment: Fantastic answers here, I am sure it will help many others after me. I do indeed have a min, I just didn't exactly copy past my code to the fiddle, which is probably a bad example to set for new people -- so thank you for mentioning that as well.

Comment: @Radu Weird! :) Either way, I think `change` is logically the best place to handle this rather than `keyup`.